# Where can I find Zend Framework Zend_Gdata component?

Tags: php, zend-framework, gdata, gdata-api

I am looking for Zend Framework Zend_Gdata component, I have already downloaded ZendFramework-minimal-2.2.0 but could not find this component in its library folder, where can I download this component of Zend framework?

Comment: I know its available in the 1.x releases of ZF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funnily enough I was looking for this recently.

http://framework.zend.com/downloads/latest

See the "Other Downloads" section, bottom of the page